# var keyword not working in LINQPad 4

Tags: c#, linqpad, var

I am trying to run a simple code in LINQPad as either C# Program or C# Statements:

```
var query = dbtable.Where(f => f.date== new DateTime(2011,10,18));
fd.Dump();
```

I get the following error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'LINQPad.User.var'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Before you ask: no, I did not create a "var" type.

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Answering my own question: 
It just realized that one of the 200+ tables in the db I am looking at is called "var". LinqPad automatically creates a "var" type.

Comment: We actually considered adding a warning to the compiler for precisely that situation -- you use "var" when it is potentially ambiguous with a type called "var" -- but then decided that nah, it's not worth the effort because no sensible person is going to run into that problem. I guess either we were wrong, or you're not a sensible person. :-)

Comment: I think of myself as a sensible person. Unfortunately, I can't say the same of the person who designed the db I am looking at :)

Comment: @ThomasMaterna, I think you should write your comment as an actual answer. You can then accept that.

Comment: By default, LINQPad capitalizes type names for tables (which prevents such problems). Presumably you've disabled capitalization in connection properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It just realized that one of the 200+ tables in the db I am looking at is called "var". LinqPad automatically creates a "var" type.

As Joe Albahari mentioned, this happens because the "Capitalize Property Names" was turned off. Thanks Joe.